# Detecting almost duplicate rows with mixed variable types

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Say for example I am trying to find duplicate values in this set, based on Name, Age and Country

```py
NAME AGE COUNTRY PROFESSION
'Fred' 23 America Banker
'Paula' 78 Germany Retired
'Fred' 23 America Banker
'Fred' 22 America Student
'Fred' 23 Brazil Police Officer
'Bingo' 36 New Zealand Money
```

To find the exact duplicates I have used:

```py
dupDF = df[df.duplicated(['NAME', 'AGE', 'COUNTRY'], keep=False)]
```

Which would give me:

```py
NAME AGE COUNTRY PROFESSION
'Fred' 23 America Banker
'Fred' 23 America Banker
```

What I really want is to match on Name, Age(+/-1) and Country, so as to return:

```py
NAME AGE COUNTRY PROFESSION
'Fred' 23 America Banker
'Fred' 23 America Banker
'Fred' 22 America Student
```

I have tried to use the solutions provided here: [Detecting almost duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958689/detecting-almost-duplicate-rows)

However I am struggling to adapt the solution to accept non-integer values.

I have also tried creating an array (as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43160595/10816095) that contains the Age +/-1 in hopes to use that to match but I can't seem to append it to the dataframe.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by all 3 columns, last column in list is integer column, then grouping by columns with same values and [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with back filling forts value, last compare by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `<`, sorting index by [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.sort_values(['NAME','COUNTRY','AGE'])
          .groupby(['NAME','COUNTRY'])['AGE'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().bfill())
          .lt(2)
          .sort_index())

df = df[mask]
print (df)
     NAME  AGE  COUNTRY PROFESSION
0  'Fred'   23  America     Banker
2  'Fred'   23  America     Banker
3  'Fred'   22  America    Student
```